# replace thunderbird version that is installed by default in such a way that the replacing version is auto updated

Tags: thunderbird, default

Ubuntu 18.04
Thunderbird updated automatically to 60.2.1 two days ago. With two problems for me:

- UI language changed from en-US to Dutch, so all short cuts I use are different..
- calendar was not present any more.

I added the en-US version of Thunderbird. As explained here, I simply extracted a tar: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux 
Now the short cuts I know work again and the calendar is back. Fine.

I think I can manage to add the en-US version to the launcher (or live without).
Less ideal is that it will not automatically update. 
***But I do want it to do automatically updates.***
So I guess that I'd rather replace the installed version (I think in /usr/lib/) with the en-US that I just unpacked. How can I do that?

Some info:

```
~$ apt policy thunderbird
thunderbird:
  Geïnstalleerd: 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Kandidaat:     1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Versietabel:
 *** 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

~$ apt policy xul-ext-lightning
xul-ext-lightning:
  Geïnstalleerd: (geen)
  Kandidaat:     1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Versietabel:
     1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: It might well be that there is no default installed Thunderbird and that I did it myself.. years ago, sorry that I do not remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question above was way too verbose. I wrote a short and clear version. That has been answered. See [replace default Dutch Thunderbird by en-US version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085163/replace-default-dutch-thunderbird-by-en-us-version)
Please close this question as duplicate - someone with proper rights.

Comment: Please delete this question. You will find **delete** near the **edit** under your question.

Comment: Not only *way too verbose*, but also bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) imo.