# replace default Dutch Thunderbird by en-US version

Tags: thunderbird, language-support

On my Ubuntu 18.04 the default Thunderbird version is Dutch.
I want that to be the en-US version. Including automatic updates etc.
How can I do that?

```
$ dpkg -l | grep thunderbird
ii  thunderbird                                   1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2           amd64        Email, RSS and newsgroup client with integrated spam filter
ii  thunderbird-gnome-support                     1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2           amd64        Email, RSS and newsgroup client - GNOME support
ii  thunderbird-locale-en                         1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2           amd64        English language pack for Thunderbird
ii  thunderbird-locale-en-us                      1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2           all          Transitional English language pack for Thunderbird
ii  thunderbird-locale-nl                         1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2           amd64        Dutch; Flemish language pack for Thunderbird
```

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep thunderbird` to the question.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the default version of an application will be determined by the language of your desktop. If you do not wish to change your default language, you can change the language ("locale") of one specific program:

```
env LANG=en_US thunderbird
```

Of course, the locale concerned must be installed on your system.

To automatically launch Thunderbird in the specific language through your regular user menus, adjust the `.desktop` launcher file for Thunderbird.

1. Copy the system wide `thunderbird.desktop` file to `.local/share/applications` under your home folder. With a terminal command, it goes like:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```

   Of course, you can use your file manager to do this if you prefer. `.local` is a hidden folder, which you will see only if you turn on **Show hidden files** in your file manager.
2. Edit the `.desktop` file you copied with your text editor and change the existing line

   ```
   Exec=thunderbird %u
   ```

   to

   ```
   Exec=env LANG=nl_NL thunderbird %u
   ```
3. Save and close the file.

Your menu system will very quickly pick up the change. Next time you select Thunderbird in your application menu, it should launch in the new language. Other users of the computer will still have Thunderbird in their default language.

Comment: thanks clearly explained.
Of course I edited the desktop file to ´Exec=env LANG=en_US thunderbird %u´

Comment: It is a hack, not real solution.

Comment: someone with enough rights might want to close https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084653/replace-thunderbird-version-that-is-installed-by-default-in-such-a-way-that-the - thanks

Comment: maybe a hack, but one I can control :)

Comment: @N0rbert just out of curiosity, why would this be a hack? An application adopts to the current locale. If you want a particular application to use another locale than your desktop's, then you have to tell the application. This is how, afaik. Why would you consider this a hack?

Comment: @N0rbert, I see, you suggest to remove the NL locale of thunderbird. This will, however, preclude other users to use the Dutch version (if needed). Note the approach I indicate does not even require root permissions.